# How to implement NetUserEnum function in Python using only ctypes?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm looking to use the NetUserEnum() function in the Win32 API using Python but would like to use ctypes instead of a library that already performs this function. I have already done this with GlobalMemoryStatusEx() and GetSystemPowerStatus() but I am struggling with NetUserEnum(). I think I am getting tripped up trying to supply `LPBYTE  *bufptr` to the function. I'm not sure how to properly structure the information and call the function correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show you're current attempt and any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) recommends, you should post your current work together with the problem that prevents you from going further.

Before anything else, the references:

- [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
- [[MS.docs]: NetUserEnum function (lmaccess.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum)

Yes, that `LPBYTE *bufptr` argument can be tricky for someone unfamiliar with *CTypes* (and also processing it afterwards).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt


DLL_NAME = "netapi32.dll"

FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0002
MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = wt.DWORD(-1)

NERR_Success = 0

NET_API_STATUS = wt.DWORD


class USER_INFO_0(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("usri0_name", wt.LPWSTR),
    ]


def user_info_type(level):
    if level == 0:
        return USER_INFO_0
    #  elif ...
    else:
        print("Invalid user info level")


def print_user_info(idx, user_info):
    print("\nUser {:d}:".format(idx))
    if isinstance(user_info, USER_INFO_0):
        print("  Name: {:s}".format(user_info.usri0_name))
    #  elif ...
    else:
        print("Invalid data")


def main(*argv):
    netapi32 = ct.WinDLL(DLL_NAME)
    NetUserEnum = netapi32.NetUserEnum
    NetUserEnum.argtypes = (wt.LPCWSTR, wt.DWORD, wt.DWORD, ct.POINTER(wt.LPBYTE), wt.DWORD, wt.LPDWORD, wt.LPDWORD, wt.PDWORD)
    NetUserEnum.restype = NET_API_STATUS
    NetApiBufferFree = netapi32.NetApiBufferFree
    NetApiBufferFree.argtypes = (wt.LPVOID,)
    NetApiBufferFree.restype = NET_API_STATUS

    info_level = 0
    filter_flag = FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
    buf = wt.LPBYTE()
    buf_len = MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH
    read, total = wt.DWORD(0), wt.DWORD(0)
    resume_handle = None

    res = NetUserEnum(None, info_level, filter_flag, ct.byref(buf), buf_len, ct.byref(read), ct.byref(total), resume_handle)
    print("\n{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(NetUserEnum.__name__, res))
    if res != NERR_Success:
        return -1
    print("{:d} (out of {:d}) entries read".format(read.value, total.value))

    UserInfoArray = user_info_type(info_level) * read.value
    users = UserInfoArray.from_address(ct.addressof(buf.contents))
    for idx, user in enumerate(users):
        print_user_info(idx, user)

    res = NetApiBufferFree(buf)
    if res != NERR_Success:
        print("Error freing buffer: {:d}".format(res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- This is an *minimum minimorum* example to get you past your current problem. There are certain aspects that need to be taken into consideration :

  - If you want more details about each user, use the appropriate *USER_INFO_** structure. You should define it (as I did for *USER_INFO_0*), and also handle it (in the wrapper functions that I wrote: *user_info_type*, *print_user_info*), and (obviously) set the appropriate level (*info_level*)
  - This minimal example is *OK* for a regular computer. But, if you attempt to run it in a domain (with tenths of thousands of users) you might experience some memory issues. In that case, you should set a decent *buf_size* (maybe *16* *MiB*s) and call *NetUserEnum* (and also *NetApiBufferFree*) in a loop, relying on *resume_handle*, while it keeps returning *ERROR_MORE_DATA*
  - Make sure the user that runs this program has enough privileges

**Output**:

> ```bat
> cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066185045]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> NetUserEnum returned: 0
> 6 (out of 6) entries read
>
> User 0:
>   Name: Administrator
>
> User 1:
>   Name: cfati
>
> User 2:
>   Name: DefaultAccount
>
> User 3:
>   Name: Guest
>
> User 4:
>   Name: test
>
> User 5:
>   Name: WDAGUtilityAccount
>
> Done.
> ```